Neo4j - after restarting the service on the server, graph not found
We had to restart the service neo4j on the server because the whole software features relying on neo4j were causing 500 errors.
So we restarted the service, and we can see neo4j is back online and showing also on the Desktop App.
But we got this error now:

production.ERROR: Neo4j errors detected. First one with code "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed" and message "Failed to invoke procedure gds.nodeSimilarity.filtered.write: Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Graph with name users does not exist on database neo4j. It might exist on another database." {"exception":"[object] (Laudis\Neo4j\Exception\Neo4jException(code: 0): Neo4j errors detected. First one with code "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed" and message "Failed to invoke procedure gds.nodeSimilarity.filtered.write: Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Graph with name users does not exist on database neo4j. It might exist on another database." at /var/www/html/XXX/vendor/laudis/neo4j-php-client/src/Exception/Neo4jException.php:50)

Just restarted the service on the server, so we expected it to be as it was before.

So this is an error about a projected graph, users, not being present to use for a GDS call after a restart of the server, and this is expected.
GDS projected graphs exist in memory only, and they do not survive restarts. This is addressed, with suggestions on backing up to deal with these issues, here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/backup-restore/

In the Neo4j Graph Data Science library, graphs and machine learning models are stored in-memory. This is necessary mainly for performance reasons but has the disadvantage that data will be lost after shutting down the database. There are already concepts to circumvent this limitation, such as running algorithms in write mode, exporting graphs to csv or storing models. The back-up and restore procedures described in this section will provide a simple and uniform way of saving graphs and models in order to load them back into memory after a database restart.

